# Output a String from an array in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans

I want to make a quiz, I want to have to output an array of questions after a form is submitted.

I know to use a bean I think but how would I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [JSTL](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) [`<c:forEach>`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html) for this. JSTL support is dependent on the servletcontainer in question. For example [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org) doesn't ship with JSTL out of the box. You can install JSTL by just dropping [jstl-1.2.jar](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar) in `/WEB-INF/lib` of your webapplication. You can use the [JSTL core tags](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/tld-summary.html) in your JSP by declaring it as per its documentation in top of your JSP file:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

You can locate an array (`Object[]`) or `List` in the `items` attribute of the `<c:forEach>` tag. You can define each item using the `var` attribute so that you can access it inside the loop:

```
<c:forEach items="${questions}" var="question">
    <p>Question: ${question}</p>
</c:forEach>
```

This does basically the same as the following in plain Java:

```
for (String question : questions) { // Assuming questions is a String[].
    System.out.println("<p>Question: " + question + "</p>");
}
```

Comment: beware forEach with a CAPITAL 'E' - save yourself :)

Answer (score 2):

With JSP 2.0, it might look something like this:

```
<% 
request.setAttribute( "questions", new String[]{"one","two","three"} );  
%>   
<c:forEach var="question" items="${questions}" varStatus="loop">  
    [${loop.index}]: ${question}<br/>  
</c:forEach>
```

where questions would be set in the code that handles the submit instead of in the JSP.

If you are using JSP 1.2:

```
<c:forEach var="question" items="${questions}" varStatus="loop">  
    <c:out value="[${loop.index}]" />: <c:out value="${question}"/><br/>  
</c:forEach>
```

Using EL and JSTL you will be able to access any Question object properties if you are storing objects in the array instead of just Strings:

```
${question.myProperty}
```

Comment: What is the significance of varStatus="loop" ?

Comment: `varStatus="loop"` defines the name of the status object that can be used in the body of the loop, in this case `loop`. It could be anything that you prefer. The status object is of type `javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagStatus`.

In the example above, `loop.index` is called in the body of the loop to retrieve the index of the current row.