# is this correct format for inserting JSTL in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl

I have JSP string array like

```
String[] valueArray = new String[valueList.size()];
valueArray = valueList.toArray(valueArray);
```

I want to use this in Javascript using JSTL

```
    var array = new Array();
 <c:forEach items="${valueArray}" var="item">
 array.push("${item}");
 </c:forEach>
```

somehow this does not work. it does not populated any values. Please help.

Comment: are you sure you have values in valueArray? ... any errors either JS or JSTL?

Comment: A side note--you can combine those two lines at the top. Replace the right side on line 1 with the right side of line 2.

Comment: What is the class of `item`?  `item.toString()` will have to return something that will result in valid JavaScript code.

Comment: @vector - there is no error but values are not populating in array. I have verified that there are values present in array. do you have any idea or example on how I can convert JSP string array to javascript using JSTL? Please help.

Comment: ... it seems ok. Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733531/output-a-string-from-an-array-in-jsp. I'd verify the js and jstl segments independently first. Test your js, then the jstl, in the end you'll narrow down the disconnect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the first set of codes are `scriptlets` in your jsp file, you should change your second set of codes as something like:

```
var array = new Array();
 <% for(int i=0; i<valueArray.length; i++){ %>
 array.push("<%= valueArray[i] %>");
 <% } %>
```

Or if they were a part of a java file (may be a servlet or an action class), you should add a line:

```
session.setAttribute("valueArray", valueArray);
```

This will add your valueArray in your session, ready to be retrieved on your jsp.